# 2-dimensional "wrapping" array

Tags: javascript, array, game

I'm writing a simple JavaScript game, which uses a 2-dimensional array as the main data structure. I wrote this function-class-thing that allows me to give any two integers, positive or negative.  This class *should* "wrap" those integers back onto the game grid.

For example:

```
var g = new Grid(10, 10)
g.set(15, -2, "hello")
g.get(5, 8); //should be "hello"
```

Anyway, I'm striving to improve my JavaScript, so I'm wondering if there are any improvements (performance, "javascriptness", etc.) that I might be able to make.

```
var Grid = (function(w, h){
    this._width = w;
    this._height = h;
    this._grid = new Array((this._width * this._height) | 0);
    this.get = function(x, y){
            var coords = _normalize(x, y);
            return this._grid[(coords.y * coords.x) + coords.x];
    }
    this.set = function(x, y, item){
            var coords = _normalize(x, y);
            this._grid[(coords.y * coords.x) + coords.x] = item;
    }
    this._normalize = function(x, y){
            if(x < 0) x = (this._width + x) % this._width;
            else if(x >= this._width) x = x % this._width ;
            if(y < 0) y = (this._height + y) % this._height;
            else if(y >= this._height) y = y % this._height;
            return {'x': x, 'y': y};
    }
});
```

Comment: What should happen if x = -11 and width = 10?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say, that my variant of normalize function is easier to understand, but at least it is linear and it works correct (as i think) with `x`, that is less than `-width`

```
this._normalize = function(x, y) {
    x = x % this._width;
    y = y % this._height;

    x = (this._width + x) % this._width;
    y = (this._height + y) % this._height;

    return {'x': x, 'y': y};
}
```

Also, you missed `this` statement in `get` and `set` functions (looks like a typo):

```
this.get = function(x, y){
    var coords = this._normalize(x, y);
    return this._grid[(coords.y * coords.x) + coords.x];
}
this.set = function(x, y, item){
    var coords = this._normalize(x, y);
    this._grid[(coords.y * coords.x) + coords.x] = item;
}
```

It is better to move `get`, `set` and `normalize` functions to Grid `prototype`.
Putting these functions in prototype will increase execution speed and require less memory for creating an instance of `Grid` because these functions will not
be created every time `Grid` instance is created.
Like this:

```
var Grid = function(w, h){
    this._width = w;
    this._height = h;
    this._grid = new Array((this._width * this._height) | 0);
};
Grid.prototype.get = function(x, y) {
    // get code
};
Grid.prototype.set = function(x, y, item){
    // set code
};
Grid.prototype._normalize = function(x, y){
    // normalize code
};
```

Comment: Come to think of it, adding this._width to x right before taking the modulo with this._width doesn't actually do anything, right? So: ```x = (this._width) + x) % this._width``` is the same as ```x %= this._width```.

Comment: It makes sense, when x < 0... But separating behavior for positive and negative values by `if` statements is also ok.

Comment: Ohh right, 'cause it's negative. Thank you :D